# Get created item information in task workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

In SharePoint 2016, I have a list that has an approval process workflow associated with it. The workflow will start the task when an item is created in the list.  Is there any way to get information from the item that was created while in the task workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the logic, if you have the list running on the item list, sure just dive into the approval action, but if your workflow is running ont he task list, that's a different story and you'll have to cross reference. My advice is to run the approval on the item list, not the task list. SharePoint designer actions will do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  I'm new to the whole SharePoint workflow thing and there's either way too much or way too little information.  Sometimes both.